# Добавить к типу столбца ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
    comment_id                         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_id                            INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users, 
    product_id                         INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products,
    parent_id                          INTEGER,
    ....
);
```

Как мне добавить `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Чтобы получилось так

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
    comment_id                         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_id                            INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    product_id                         INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products ON DELETE CASCADE,
    parent_id                          INTEGER,
    ....
);
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE ADD ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы хотите добавить ограничение внешнего ключа `ON DELETE CASCADE` в существующую таблицу, вам необходимо выполнить следующие шаги:

1.Удалить существующее ограничение внешнего ключа.

```
ALTER TABLE comments
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>;
```

2.Добавить новое ограничение внешнего ключа с `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

```
ALTER TABLE comments
ADD CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>
FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
REFERENCES products(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

подробнее в [туториале](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/)

Возможно вы не знаете имена ваших констрейнов. Для поиска можно использовать системный каталог [pg_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html).

Примерно таким запросом:

```
SELECT conname
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE conrelid =
    (SELECT oid 
    FROM pg_class
    WHERE relname LIKE 'products');
```

**PS**

Но вообще все это можно было найти по ссылке в доку из прошлого ответа.